# Resuming a stopped thread using flag

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have the following code :

```
class SoundPlayback
{ 
        protected volatile bool _playing;
        public bool Playing {...}

        protected void Begin()
        {
            while (Playing && _sheet.TimeTick != 0)
            {
                _sheet.PlaySounds();
                Thread.Sleep(_sheet.TimeTick);
            }
            _playing = false;
        }
}
```

I have a thread calling Begin() with thread start, which works fine for the first time around, but when _playing is false and I want to resume the playback, I'm unable to.
Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your thread terminates once `_playing` is set to `false`. So you can't resume it.

Comment: thread.Sleep is always a bad idea except for testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Threads (*any* threads, not just .Net):

- Sleep: BAD
- Block-on-Event: GOOD

Take a look at "Synchronization Essentials" in this most excellent tutorial:

- http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx#_Synchronization

And change your loop to:

1) Call some other function do to the "work"

2) rely on some global "done" variable (instead of exiting when "TimeTick != 0"!!!!!)

Comment: Thanks! This loop was really just for testing some other part of code that didn't quite work, and I'm also new to threading. That tutorial looks really good, thank you! This is exactly what I needed.